# How can you write your CSS within an Anonymous Laravel Component?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I wan't to keep component-specific styles inside each component (like a [Vue SFC](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html)). It would look something like this:

```html
<!-- base-button.blade.php -->
<button class="btn">
  {{ $slot }}
</button>

<style>
  .btn { /* Some styles */ }
</style>
```

Is there a way to do this? If I paste the code above, that `style` tag gets removed from the rendered HTML.

### I tried [sections](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#section-directives)

```php
{{-- layout.blade.php --}}
@hasSection('style')
  @yield('style')
@endif

{{-- base-button.blade.php --}}
@section('style')
  <style>
    .btn {
      /* Some styles */
    }
  </style>
@endsection
```

### I tried [stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#stacks)

```php
{{-- layout.blade.php --}}
@stack('styles')

{{-- base-button.blade.php --}}
@push('styles')
  <style>
    .btn {
      /* Some styles */
    }
  </style>
@endpush
```

But none of them render any `style` tag.

Comment: You can use the 'push' and 'stack' blade directives: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#stacks

Comment: @KarlHill I updated my question. Stacks don't seem to work either.

Comment: What do you mean it gets removed? Blade shouldn't care about your content. I'm using `<style>` in my blade files and don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the @push directive to push the styles into a stack named 'styles'.

```
<!-- components/base-button.blade.php -->
<button class="btn">
  {{ $slot }}
</button>

@push('styles')
  <style>
    .btn {
      /* Some styles */
    }
  </style>
@endpush
```

Render the pushed styles using the @stack directive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Laravel</title>
  @stack('styles')
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Your content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @luvejo This doesn't work?